# Which tool will allow me to merge multiple folders in a single folder based on modification date

Tags: windows, windows-7

I need to merge multiple (more than two) folders that have a similar tree and file structure

For example if I have these folders

```
FolderA/DB/A.SQL - last modified: yesterday
FolderA/DB/F.SQL
FolderA/WebSite/one.aspx - last modified: today

FolderB/DB/A.SQL - last modified: today
FolderB/DB/C.SQL
FolderB/WebSite/one.aspx - last modified: yesterday
FolderB/WebSite/two.aspx 

FolderC/DB/B.SQL
FolderC/WebSite/three.aspx
```

The merged single folder should contain

```
Merged/DB/A.SQL - last modified: today (taken from FolderB)
Merged/DB/B.SQL
Merged/DB/C.SQL
Merged/DB/F.SQL
Merged/WebSite/one.aspx - last modified: today (taken from FolderA)
Merged/WebSite/two.aspx 
Merged/WebSite/three.aspx
```

**Which tool will allow me to do this ? Winmerge only merges TWO folders. And I need to merge any number of folders (not just 3 like in the example) and each folder can contain multiple files**

**I am asking this because if the tool does not exist I will write it on my own but I rather use the wheel than reinvent it**

Comment: @MauricioGracia Join this http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60887/software-recommendations   While it doesn't solve your current question, it would be nice to have a stackoverflow place were we can safely ask these types of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently most of the tools out there work on two folders or they merge the files but dont keep the folder structure and many version cost money but dont perform the exact task that I need.

**I have already to develop this, if any one needs this tool let me know I will share it**

Answer (score 0):

How about any version-control tools like: SVN, Git or whatever else:

1. With git you can init empty repository locally and commit 1st folder into.
2. Than copy over the 2nd folder replacing the files. Then in commit dialog - review changes, revert if previous (which already in repo) file state changes had higher priority.
3. Commit the new state.
4. Repeat steps 2-3 for any number of such folders.

I'm using these technique when merging complex folder structures which are not version controlled and got simultaneous changes for some reason.

Comment: this sounds like an alternative, but the idea is to remove as much as posible, the manual intervention over the "merge" process. and if I have a file "alterTableXX.sql" on folder 1 and then "alterTableXX.sql" on folder 2 with different alter statements I need to concatenate those changes. If I use a repository one whil replece the other or I will have to check each case by hand. In my case each folder is like a "release" of a fix/feature that can be applied separatedly

Comment: @Mauricio Gracia, the case with simultaneous changes in the same file is the perfect use-case for version-control to manage. You will be able to review/edit every change. But I agree it might appear to be a lot of manual work.

Answer (score 0):

I wasted half an hour on [RichCopy](https://superuser.com/questions/352801/how-can-i-merge-two-folders-in-windows) (not feasible for two thousands folders) and PowerShell (too complicated) before I fall back to [xcopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCOPY):

1. In command prompt, go to the folder containing FolderA, FolderB, FolderC etc.
2. Run `md Merged` to create destination folder.
3. Run xcopy in a for loop:

> for /D %%i in (*) do xcopy "%%i" Merged\ /e /h /d /y

Breakdowns:

- `for /D %%i in (*) do` - repeat for each directory.
- `xcopy "%%i" Merged\` - copy directory contents to "merged" folder.
- `/e` - copy recursively, including empty directory.
- `/h` - don't skip hidden and system files.
- `/d` - overwrite only if newer.
- `/y` - don't ask, just overwrite.